# managing large state classes in flutter bloc

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

```
class AddTaskState extends Equatable {
  final ErrorModel? errorModel;
  final AddTaskEntity? addTaskEntity;
```

This is a snippet of my class which contain a state. I use Flutter and bloc. Class ErrorModel has 3 or 4 fields and AddTaskEntity has 8 fields. It doesnt make sens to duplicate the code and paste to AddTaskState 12 fields so I decided to create separate classes. The thing is how I should manage them?

e.g. in bloc I have:

```
on<OnDoSth>((event, emit) {
  emit(state.copyWith(addTaskEntity: state.addTaskEntity.copyWith(date: event.date)));
});
```

its double copyWith. What in case when in my model will be additional model or 2? It will be more  copywith so I suppose it won't be effective?